# bootstrapValidator: Reset clears required icons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm initializing bootstrapValidator as given in the link:

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/showing-required-icon/

But when I reset the form, how can I show the required icons again? I'm using the following code to reset the form:

```
$(form).data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm('resetForm', true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you call resetForm, you need to re-call your initialization code for each field in the form.  For example, to reset the 'name' field:

```
var field = $('#productForm input[name="name"]');
field.trigger('init.field.bv', { 
    bv: $('#productForm').data('bootstrapValidator'),
    field:'name',
    element:field})
```

I believe you could set this up with a `$.each` but I didn't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job ! After a resetForm, all the fields are in 'NOT_VALIDATED' state and the plugin trigger an event.

```
      $('#YourForm').on('status.field.bv', function(e, data)
        {
            if( data.status == 'NOT_VALIDATED')
            {
                var $parent    = data.element.parents('.form-group'),
                    $icon      = $parent.find('.form-control-feedback[data-bv-icon-for="' + data.field + '"]'),
                    options    = data.bv.getOptions(),                      // Entire options
                    validators = data.bv.getOptions(data.field).validators; // The field validators

                if (validators.notEmpty && options.feedbackIcons && options.feedbackIcons.required) {
                    $icon.addClass(options.feedbackIcons.required).show();
                }
            }
        });
```